# Downloaded or saved files do not appear on the main monitor but appear on the first monitor amont the three

Tags: multiple-monitors

I'm using 3 monitors, as shown in the screenshot. Until now, for example, when I downloaded something from the net, or saved a file the `file save dialog` was displayed on the 3rd monitor which I defined as main display. But for a few days it has been displaying on monitor 1. I don't understand why this change happened. What should I do to make the dialog box appear on the 3rd monitor again?

Note: I re-downloaded the display driver, no change in the result.

[image]

Comment: ok, so you are worried about window-position for the applications you use to open commonly downloaded file types. is that correct?

Comment: Unclear : How can anything be downloaded to a *monitor* ?

Comment: Nothing downloads "to a monitor". Monitors are just picture screens, and they do not store anything. Files download to storage on your Drives. What you may be trying to describe is what Frank Thomas is referring to: Programs, such as File Explorer or those that open the files you are downloading, are opening on a monitor other than the one you prefer. Do you know how to move program windows between your monitors? Do programs you move to another monitor REMEMBER which monitor they were last opened on?

Comment: Alternately, if you're talking about the ICONS for the downloaded files, IF you have set your download directory in your browser to be your desktop, these typically are placed starting with whichever screen you set as your Main display, and if that one is fully they'll then proceed numerically through your screens.

Comment: (1) What is the OS? In case of Linux: what is the desktop environment? compositor? etc. Probably many users can guess this from the screenshot and probably this is not Linux, but such basic information should always be explicitly stated. (2) What programs are affected? All programs? Some specific program(s)?

Answer (score 2):

Because you have `Remember window locations based on monitor connection`, it may be that all you have to do is to shift the dialog window, when it appears to monitor 3.  It should then display on monitor 3 from then on.